# TYPO3 Saltedpassword : how to convert a salted password back to plain text

Tags: typo3, extbase

In my ext. I auto generate a password that is converted to a salted password and stored in the DB.
The generation of the password is done with the method provided in the saltedpassword ext.

At the end of the registration process of my application, I would like to show the password in plain text. 
As far as I can tell, there is no method available in the salted password extension to convert a password back to plain text.

How can I do this?

tnx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no possibility to reverse a hashed string back to the original string. If you found a service which offers that, they using rainbow tables. See http://md5.gromweb.com/. For this reason there is no reverse function inside the saltedpassword extension.

You also should ask yourself why you wanna show the user the password. This will put your extension into a bad light security wise. As a user I would think that you save my password as plain text into the database.

But to answer your question: You can of course save the plain password in the session and print it at the end of registration process.

Comment: OK, this explains why there is no revere method.
Saving in a session was also an idea and i'll do it like that.